# Not responsive height in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

do you know if it is possible to express the height of a specific LWC in  %?
I want to make it responsive, actually when I try to set an height like :

`height: 100%`

it seems that the attribute is ignored and the actual height is based on the child node's height

Here is an example:

```
   <template>

    <lightning-cardvariant="Narrow"style="height:100%;">
    //the component height is not 100%
    </lightning-card>

   </template>
```

Comment: Can you add the minimal required code to your question to understand your actual issue?

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Also, when you say the attribute is ignored and the actual height is based on the child node's height, what does it mean? Can you add a screenshot to make it clear?

Comment: Sure, I added two snapshot here [link](https://imgur.com/a/7YtVDvm) . In both snaps the height depends on how many child rows are shown, but I wish that the height is always 100% of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made slight change to your code.

Check out this Playground [LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/q-RK0yzD/2/edit)

Use `height : 90vh` i.e - 90% of viewport

Comment: Thank you it works!

Comment: Happy to help @J.Dillinger